# icarousel Vertical Scroll Effect on tableview with images

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

i am trying to apply iCarousel vertical type effect on tableview cell images.
But not set vertical scroll effect.
i also check this,
https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel
but in this example only set horizontal scroll effect. and i want to set Vertical type effect.
so , suggest me some good demo link or with proper code solution.

this is some code for that ...

```
- (CATransform3D)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel itemTransformForOffset:(CGFloat)offset baseTransform:(CATransform3D)transform {

    const CGFloat centerItemZoom = 1.6;
    const CGFloat centerItemSpacing = 1.5;

    CGFloat spacing = [self carousel:carousel valueForOption:iCarouselOptionSpacing withDefault:1.0f];
    CGFloat absClampedOffset = MIN(1.0, fabs(offset));
    CGFloat clampedOffset = MIN(1.0, MAX(-1.0, offset));
    CGFloat scaleFactor = 1.0 + absClampedOffset * (1.0/centerItemZoom - 1.0);
    offset = (scaleFactor * offset + scaleFactor * (centerItemSpacing - 1.0) * clampedOffset) * carousel.itemWidth * spacing;

    if (carousel.vertical)
    {
        transform = CATransform3DTranslate(transform, 0.0f, offset, -absClampedOffset);
    }
    else
    {
        transform = CATransform3DTranslate(transform, offset, 0.0f, -absClampedOffset);
    }

    transform = CATransform3DScale(transform, scaleFactor, scaleFactor, 2.0f);

    return transform; 
}
```

but not work for my requirement.
Thank x in advance

Answer (score 1):

if you want vertical scroll add this in your code

```
    self.carousel.vertical = !self.carousel.vertical;
```

Comment: @welcome Blackbird.. feel free to ask anything you need

Comment: means can u show m or explain more how u  want and what are you getting now

Comment: palwevijay42@gmail.com

Comment: plz check yor emal and check .apk file. i want to apply animation like in detail page of tableview .

Comment: got it my email bro. ?

Comment: ur working with android bro, actully im a ios developer so is it possible for you to send ipa

Comment: bro.. i have only .apk file for animation reference. android me jese implement kiya he vesa animation iPhone me karna he.

Comment: sry was in meeting and need to again, which type of icarousel ur android team is using for this

Comment: NP bro., i dont know any from android side.. bro.

Comment: i think they used recycle view for tableview and animation.. but no more idea about that...

Comment: hey have you check that is android team using icarousol or anything else so that we can invest time on same